# Swift: Sharing videos using ActivityViewController works only for iMessages and doesn't work for any other

Tags: ios, swift

```
var selectedVideoArray: Array<Any> = []

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
if (shareEnabled) {
            let selectedVideo = fetchResult[indexPath.row]
            self.selectedVideos.add(selectedVideo)

            var videoPhAsset: PHAsset!
            videoPhAsset = fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.row)

            PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: videoPhAsset, options: nil, resultHandler: { (AVAsset, AVAudio, info) in

                var assetVideoUrl: NSURL
                var avUrlAsset: AVURLAsset
                avUrlAsset = AVAsset as! AVURLAsset
                assetVideoUrl = (avUrlAsset.url as? NSURL)!
                self.selectedVideoArray.append(assetVideoUrl.filePathURL!)
            })
        }
}


@IBAction func shareVideos(_ sender: Any) {

let moreAction = UIAlertAction(title: "More", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) -> Void in

            let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: self.selectedVideoArray, applicationActivities:nil)

            activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash

            self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) { (action) -> Void in

        }

        actionSheet.addAction(moreAction)
        actionSheet.addAction(dismissAction)

        present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am trying to share videos using social framework and ActivityViewController but it only works for iMessages and does not work for any other social networking or mail. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Social networks does not support Video sharing with default share sheet. You will need to share video with custom method separately for all networks..